# Use state inside vuex.store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vuex

My problem is that after I refresh page I overwrite my currentLanguge state:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import vuexI18n from "vuex-i18n";
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";
import toPolish from "./../translations/toPolish";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        currentLanguage: ''
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {},
    plugins: [createPersistedState()]
});

Vue.use(vuexI18n.plugin, store);
Vue.i18n.add("pl", toPolish);
Vue.i18n.set(store.state.currentLanguage || store.state.currentLanguage);
export default store;
```

So even if user change language after refresh it will have firstly value of empty string and then after this line

`Vue.i18n.set(store.state.currentLanguage || navigator.language);`

it will set it back to browser language which I don't want but I also can't figure out how to fix it. I would have to do something like

```
    state: {
        currentLanguage: store.state.currentLanguage || ''
    },
```

So it will set previous value if there is some or empty string if store.state.currectLanguage is empty. But this solution doesn't work and give error:

> store.js?adc6:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: Probably it's better to store a language setting in a cookie. Or in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I wasn't even commiting any mutation in language change function so I didn't change value in vuex storage actually I was only changing value in component which was re-rendering selected flag.

So after changing mutations to:

```
mutations: {
    changeLang: (state, response) => {
        if(response) {
            state.currentLanguage = response;
        }
    }
},
```

and in function which is changing language i commit this mutation:

```
changeLanguage(lang) {
    Vue.i18n.set(lang);
    this.selectedLanguage = lang;
    this.$store.commit('changeLang', lang);
}
```

And now everything works fine. At first load language is browser language after user change it and refresh it stay changed.